# $event->isNew not working as expected after Craft 3.2 update

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, events

Pre Craft 3.2, you could do something like this if you wanted to perform an action in the event you just saved a new entry:

```
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\ModelEvent;

Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
    function(ModelEvent $event) {
        $entry = $event->sender;
        $isNew = $event->isNew;

        if ($isNew) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
);
```

However, after the update, this code doesn't work as it used to. `$isNew` always gets evaluated to `true` whether resaving a pre existing entry or editing a yet-to-be-saved entry (the autosave kicks in after a couple of seconds while you're editing).

I've tried doing something like this to check if the entry is being resaved but it still gets evaluated to `true`:

```
$isBrandNew = false;
if ($event->isNew && ! $entry->propagating && ! $entry->resaving) {
    $isBrandNew = true;
}

if ($isBrandNew) {
    // do something
}
```

How do I fix this so that my code only runs after a *brand new* entry was just created, like it did before Craft 3.2?

Answer (score 3):

We just released Craft 3.2.5 which should fix this for you.

For more context about why this happened in the first place, see https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4589.

Comment: Useful also to add that you need to check for draft/revision using `ElementHelper`: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4621#issuecomment-513485799